# How do I return list of elements by attribute value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I've done the research and do not understand why my Linq query is not working. I am trying to return a list of "Grant" elements from this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <ArrayOfMapItem>
    <MapItem>
      <Id xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">7D2B99FA-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Id>
      <Map xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">6557A558-7ED9-4199-8585-6FD8610E4119</Map>
      <ServiceCollectionId xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">69DB37D4-8A29-4C4E-8671-6C054B9F62E5</ServiceCollectionId>
      <ServiceCollectionName xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">S-AVCL-CC-01-DF8_SC</ServiceCollectionName>
      <Services xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">S-AVCL-CC-01-DF8</Services>
      <Position xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">1350</Position>
    </MapItem>
    <MapItem>
      <Id xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">7D2B99FC-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Id>
      <Map xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">80703716-4BCE-4465-902E-6B92A9BD41AC</Map>
      <ServiceCollectionId xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">A8266306-9384-4CAA-9746-DD9279F9A27E</ServiceCollectionId>
      <ServiceCollectionName xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">S-AVCL-CC-02-DF8_SC</ServiceCollectionName>
      <Services xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">S-AVCL-CC-02-DF8</Services>
      <Position xmlns="Private.CO.path.type">1351</Position>
    </MapItem>
  </ArrayOfMapItem>
  <GrantArrays>
    <GrantArray>
      <Grant ResourceId="6557a558-7ed9-4199-8585-6fd8610e4119" PrincipalExternalId="royce" PrincipalType="Group" ResType="Package" Right="Access">
        <Conditions xmlns="http://www.here.com/location/bss">
          <TimeExpiration Start="2014-05-01T07:00:00" End="9999-12-31T23:59:59.997" Type="TimeExpiration" Expiration="9999-12-31T23:59:59" />
        </Conditions>
      </Grant>
      <Grant ResourceId="6557a558-7ed9-4199-8585-6fd8610e4119" PrincipalExternalId="peter" PrincipalType="Group" ResType="Package" Right="Access">
        <Conditions xmlns="http://www.here.com/location/bss">
          <TimeExpiration Start="2014-04-04T19:18:04.963" End="9999-12-31T23:59:59.997" Type="TimeExpiration" Expiration="9999-12-31T23:59:59" />
        </Conditions>
      </Grant>
    </GrantArray>
    <GrantArray>
      <Grant ResourceId="80703716-4bce-4465-902e-6b92a9bd41ac" PrincipalExternalId="royce" PrincipalType="Group" ResType="Package" Right="Access">
        <Conditions xmlns="http://www.here.com/location/bss">
          <TimeExpiration Start="2014-05-01T07:00:00" End="9999-12-31T23:59:59.997" Type="TimeExpiration" Expiration="9999-12-31T23:59:59" />
        </Conditions>
      </Grant>
      <Grant ResourceId="80703716-4bce-4465-902e-6b92a9bd41ac" PrincipalExternalId="peter" PrincipalType="Group" ResType="Package" Right="Access">
        <Conditions xmlns="http://www.here.com/location/bss">
          <TimeExpiration Start="2014-04-04T19:18:05.2" End="9999-12-31T23:59:59.997" Type="TimeExpiration" Expiration="9999-12-31T23:59:59" />
        </Conditions>
      </Grant>
    </GrantArray>
  </GrantArrays>
</root>
```

I am applying the Linq query in this method, passing the method an Attribute value for ResourceId that is known to exist:

```
        private static void CheckGrantChanges(string approvemapid) //, string checkmapid)
    {
        // approvemapid = "6557a558-7ed9-4199-8585-6fd8610e4119". value confirmed several times

        var docApproved = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Tools\WorkOnChannelChecker\Daily11ApprovedMapping.xml");

        var approveGrants = docApproved.Descendants("GrantArray");

        var queryApproved = from a in approveGrants.Elements("Grant")
                            where a.Attribute("ResourceId").Value == approvemapid
                            select a;
    }
```

I expect to have two Grant elements returned in "queryApproved", but it keeps coming back empty. Please tell me what it is I am misunderstanding in this process?
Thanks ahead of time for you help!

Comment: might just be "{yourguid}" ... means you have to remove the braces...

Comment: or you use uppercase and lowercase letters... do ´where a.Attribute("ResourceId").Value.Equals(approvemapid,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )´

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Florian. Problem was the string comparison. Changing the query to:
...

```
            var queryApproved = from a in approveGrants.Elements("Grant")
                            where a.Attribute("ResourceId").Value.Equals(approvemapid,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                            select a;
```

...
Solved the problem.